# Wrong Keymap on Mac Keyboard - "<" and "^" are switched

Tags: keyboard

Since upgrading to *El Capitan* my Keyboard layout has changed and is driving me crazy:

The key "<" which should be right beside the Left Shift Key is now switched with the "^" key.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please specify what language keyboard you use -- French azerty?  Have you verified that your desired keyboard is the Only one on the list in system prefs/keyboard/input sources?

Comment: It's German QWERTZ. Yes, there is only one Keyboard in the List

Answer (score 8):

I know this will not help you but maybe others (worked for me for german layout on external keyboard):

If "<" and "^" are switched on an external keyboard, the easiest way to "switch" them back is: if you are asked to press the button right to the left shift key (on german layout "<") you simply press the button it is switched with, afterwards everything will work as normal.

Comment: Too stupid and simple :D but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can switch those around again using the Karabiner app or by creating a custom layout with Ukelele.

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/